# Galculator does not compile

Tags: compiling, gtk, lubuntu

I'm trying to compile `galculator-2.0.1` but when I run `make` I get some errors like

```
galculator-general_functions.o: In function `set_button_color':
/home/user/Downloads/galculator-2.0.1/src/general_functions.c:268: undefined reference to `GTK_COLOR_CHOOSER'
```

I'm using Lubuntu 11.10. I read something about update to gtk3 but I don't want to install many thins or update almost the whole LXDE.

What should I install to solve the problem?

Comment: Where did you get the source code?

Comment: From here https://sourceforge.net/projects/galculator/
The green button.

Comment: Why compile it from source? Why not use the one provided by ubuntu?

Comment: This new version is not available yet, I guess.

Comment: You probably need one or more .....-dev packages, but since you didn't include much of the error messages, I cannot tell which. Just search the internet for missing funtion names and related ...-dev packages that will provide you with the related header files.

Comment: Here are some errors: galculator-general_functions.o: In function `set_button_color': /home/thiago/Downloads/galculator-2.0.1/src/general_functions.c:268: undefined reference to `GTK_COLOR_CHOOSER'
/home/thiago/Downloads/galculator-2.0.1/src/general_functions.c:268: undefined reference to `gtk_color_chooser_set_rgba'

Comment: @Sigur Have you checked how GTK_COLOR_CHOOSER is declared/defined in the header files?

Comment: @Karlson, thanks. But I have no idea how to check this. I'm just trying to compile to learn a little bit. I'll try something.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution with Debian-based distributions (like lubuntu) is the use of `build-dep` action of `apt-get`.

Run `sudo apt-get build-dep galculator` and try to compile again. It should compile as intended. Make sure you have your `deb-src` repositories activated in your `sources.list` file.